# How to support variable length arrays in OpenCL linux

Tags: arrays, variables, opencl

My kernel contains some private variable length arrays. The kernel can be compiled and executed in Mac, but fails in Linux OpenCL. In linux, the error is `error: variable length arrays are not supported in OpenCL`. So, how to support variable length arrays in Linux OpenCL?

Comment: pass necessary n value to kernel string by value, not name so it becomes __local float array[12345] instead of __local float array[n]. If this is already in effect then you should query max size from opencl api.

Answer (score 0):

Try  OpenCL KMA (Kernel Memory Allocator)
see  https://github.com/RSpliet/KMA

It  implements  malloc and free for OpenCL